# $ \int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}\, dx$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve this irrational integral $$ \int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}\, dx$$
doing the substitution

$$ x= \frac{t^2}{1-2 t}$$
according to the rule.

So the integral becomes:
$$  \int \frac{-2t^6}{(1-2t)^4}\, dt= \int (-\frac{1}{8}t^2-\frac{1}{4}t-\frac{5}{16}+\frac{1}{16}\frac{-80t^3+90t^2-36t+5}{(1-2t)^4})\, dt=\int (-\frac{1}{8}t^2-\frac{1}{4}t-\frac{5}{16}+\frac{1}{16}(\frac{10}{1-2t}-\frac{15}{2} \frac{1}{(1-2t)^2}+\frac{3}{(1-2t)^3}-\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{(1-2t)^4}))\, dt=-\frac{1}{24}t^3-\frac{1}{8}t^2-\frac{5}{16}t-\frac{5}{16}\cdot \ln|1-2t|
-\frac{15}{64}\frac{1}{1-2t}+\frac{3}{64} \frac{1}{(1-2t)^2}-\frac{1}{16 \cdot 12} \frac{1}{(1-2t)^3}+cost $$
with $t=-x+ \sqrt{x^2+x}$.

The final result according to my book is instead $(\frac{1}{3}x^2-\frac{5}{12}x+\frac{15}{24})\sqrt{x^2+x}-\frac{5}{16}\ln( x+\frac{1}{2}+ \sqrt{x^2+x})$

And trying to obtain the same solution putting t in the formulas I'm definitely lost in the calculation...
I don't understant why this difference in the complexity of the solution...
Can someone show me where I'm making mistakes?

Answer (score 8):

**Just for your curiosity** *since you already received @hamam_Abdallah's answer.*

You can compute this integral musch faster with a different change of variable.

Because of the denominator, let $x=\sinh^2(t)$
$$\int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}\, dx=2 \int \sinh ^6(t)\,dt$$

Now, using the multiple angle formulae
$$\sinh ^6(t)=\frac{15}{32} \cosh (2 t)-\frac{3}{16} \cosh (4 t)+\frac{1}{32} \cosh (6
   t)-\frac{5}{16}$$ and everything becomes simple.

Comment: I have never found this multiple angle formulae, how can i obtain it?

Comment: @Anne
$$$$

$$\sinh^6(t) = \left(\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}\right)^6 = \frac1{64}\left[(e^{6t}+e^{-6t})-6(e^{4t}+e^{-4t})+15(e^{2t}+2^{-2t})-20\right]$$

Could you take from here?

Answer (score 3):

$$x=\frac{t^2}{1-2t}$$

$$dx=\frac{2t(1-2t)+2t^2}{(1-2t)^2}dt$$
$$=\frac{2(t-t^2)}{(1-2t)^2}dt$$

$$\sqrt{x^2+x}=x+t=\frac{t-t^2}{1-2t}$$

$$\frac{x^3dx}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}=$$
$$\frac{t^6}{(1-2t)^3}\frac{1-2t}{t-t^2}\frac{2(t-t^2)dt}{(1-2t)^2}$$
$$=\frac{2t^6dt}{(1-2t)^4}$$

To make the integration easier, put $$u=2t$$
to get
$$\frac{1}{64}\int \frac{u^6du}{(1-u)^4}$$
$$=\frac{1}{64}\int \frac{(u^6-u^5+u^5-u^4+u^4-u^3+u^3)du}{(1-u)^4}$$
Here is an other way
$$x^2+x=(x+\frac 12)^2-\frac 14$$
put
$$x+\frac 12=\frac 12\cosh(t)$$

Comment: ok I did it , didn't I?

Comment: @Anne You found $-2t^6 $ while i found $+2t^6$

Comment: $\sqrt{t^2+1-2t}=t-1$ or $1-t$ so you found the - sign

Comment: @Anne Look at some modification.

Comment: question how did you get x equal that? :)

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I'm not so sure that the position simplify the calculations

Answer (score 1):

Prior to any substitution, apply the reduction formula
$$\int \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}\, dx=I_n=\frac{x^{n-1}}n \sqrt{x^2+x}
-\frac{2n-1}{2n}I_{n-1}
$$
(obtained via IBP) successively  to simplify
$$\int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}\, dx=
\left(\frac{x^2}3 -\frac{5x}{12}+\frac58\right) \sqrt{x^2+x}
-\frac5{16}I_0
$$
where $I_0=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x}}\, dx=
\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+x}}{x+\frac12} $.